# pip freeze without dependencies of installed packages

Tags: python, pip, requirements.txt

When I do `pip freeze` I get the packages I've explicitly installed plus those packages that are dependencies of those packages.

For example:

```
$ pip install fabric
...
$ pip freeze
Fabric==1.0.1
paramiko==1.7.6
pycrypto==2.3
```

Ok fine but then I move to install this requirements.txt on another environment with `pip install` I'd get the same result with the last 2 lines removed.

So my question is: how I can I create the most simplified requirements.txt where all calculable dependencies are not shown?

Answer (score 132, accepted):

Now there is (disclaimer: I did it).

All you need is to install `pip-chill` from PyPI and run `pip-chill` from your Python environment.

If you are feeling adventurous and don't want to pin versions (or want to use pip-compile), you can use `pip-chill --no-version` and it'll give you the minimal requirements for your current environment.

https://github.com/rbanffy/pip-chill

Comment: Note pip-chill requires pip>=10. On pip==9 it raises "No module named pip._internal". Fixed within the virtualenv by `pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: This should be merged into pip itself. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much for this. Have you tried to contributing this to pip itself?

Comment: FYI: The tool has a bug that makes it so packages won't show up if they're a dependency of another top-level package https://github.com/rbanffy/pip-chill/issues/49 (getting it with Flask)

Comment: Thanks, @GammaGames. I think I missed the issue and should have been much less slow at responding. I think I have a good solution, but I'd appreciate your input and the one from others who identified the issue.

Comment: This is nice. Want to add a valuable improvement? Add the ability to pin minimum and less than next major, meaning, turn `pkg==1.2.3` into `pkg>=1.2.3,<2`

Comment: @Wyrmwood: That's an idea - compute the intersection of all restrictions about a certain package. I'm not sure, though, this information is available after the package is installed. We should continue this conversation on GitHub.

Answer (score 12):

There is no way to create "the most simplified requirements.txt" with pip - and I don't know if you would need it in this case.

It is good to have **all packages** in the requirements.txt, because you are sure about what dependencies versions work with your environment.

Think about paramiko getting updated, and breaking backwards compatibilities: you would have problems.

Comment: I don't think `all packages` is correct. Since `pip install -r requirements.txt` will install dependency automatically, we just need the root/original packages.

Comment: @NamGVU: I said it's "good to have all packages," not that it's a must. It's a good practice to specify all packages because you have better control of your environment. Think about a given package A that depends on B==1.0.0 and B depends on C (any version). The Package A only has to require B==1.0, but if for any reason package C is updated in a backward incompatible way, package A might have trouble (because it didn't specify what version of package C is guaranteed to work). Thus, it's **safer** for A to specify both B==1.0.0 **and** a version of C that was tested and you know it works.

Comment: The correct/compatible vesion of C is defined by B not A; and that works automatically by pip. Thanks for sharing anyway.

Comment: @NamGVU: the Python world isn't perfect and a lot of times people don't specify strict versions for their immediate dependencies. I've seen this problem happen many times. One case that comes to mind is when `python-statsd` **mistakenly** specified `mock` (no pinned version) as a dependency and all of a sudden the newest version of `mock` requires a different version of `setuptools`. Some of my servers broke because they used `python-statsd==1.6.0` and didn't specify the full hierarchy of dependencies. See https://git.io/vPWIW and https://github.com/testing-cabal/mock/issues/261

Comment: Thanks for great  sharing with such specific sample on `python-statsd`; and then, I totally agree to attach the version here. I also agree there is something wrong with `pip` developer team.

Comment: By the way, I love Python and want to join to make it perfect.  Where we can **read the dependency definition** for one pip package @hugotavares?

Answer (score 7):

I think the simply way to remove version is cut `-d"=" -f1` after having run `pip freeze`.

```
pip3 freeze | cut -d"=" -f1
```

Answer (score 4):

[pipdeptree](https://github.com/naiquevin/pipdeptree) is another option.

It produces full requirements.txt (with `pipdeptree -f`) like this:

```
jupyter==1.0.0
  ipykernel==5.4.3
    ipython==7.19.0
      backcall==0.2.0
      decorator==4.4.2
      jedi==0.17.2
        parso==0.7.1
```

This file serves two purposes:

- Used as a traditional requirements.txt fed to `pip install`;
- Used as a developer-friendly packages list (like the one created by `pip-chill`) simply with `grep '^\w' requirements.txt`.