# tell pip to install the dependencies of packages listed in a requirement file

Tags: python, pip, requirements.txt

Developing a Django web app, I have a list of packages I need to install in a virtualenv.  Say:

```
Django==1.3.1
--extra-index-url=http://dist.pinaxproject.com/dev/
Pinax==0.9b1.dev10
git+git://github.com/pinax/pinax-theme-bootstrap.git@cff4f5bbe9f87f0c67ee9ada9aa8ae82978f9890
# and other packages
```

Initially I installed them manually, one by one, along the development. This installed the required dependencies and I finally used `pip freeze` before deploying the app.

Problem is, as I upgraded some packages, some dependencies are no longer used nor required but they keep being listed by `pip freeze`.

Now, I'd like to set up a new virtualenv this way:

- put the needed packages (without their dependencies) in a requirement file, 
  like `manual-requirements.txt`
- install them with their dependencies 
  `pip install -r manual-requirement.txt` (← problem, this does not install the dependencies)
- freeze the full virtualenv 
  `pip freeze -r manual-requirements.txt > full-requirements.txt`
  and deploy.

Any way to do this without manually re-installing the packages in a new virtualenv to get their dependencies ? This would be error-prone and I'd like to automate the process of cleaning the virtualenv from no-longer-needed old dependencies.

**edit:** actually, pip *does* install dependencies not explicitly listed in the requirement file, even if [the documentation](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/requirements.html) tells us that such files are flat. I was wrong about which dependencies i expected to be installed. I'll let this question for anyone in doubt about pip not installing all dependencies.

Comment: So... what is the problem exactly? Do you know which are your "first level" dependencies?

Comment: Yes, I've listed them in manual-requirements.txt. Problem is: pip does not install their dependencies (ie. "second level") if I use a requirement file while they get installed if i manually `pip install django; pip install pinax; etc.`.

Comment: As long as you use the exact versions of the required packages, there should be no changes in its dependencies. But if you do not use exact versions, how can you guarantee that your application still works?

Comment: I know, I eventually use exact versions for testing and deployment. My issue concerns the no longer needed "2nd level" dependencies after some upgrades of my "1st level" dependencies. I'd like to rebuild the full deps list from scratch to drop what's not anymore needed and avoid any conflicts.

Comment: As the answer by @mac which you marked as *accepted* is not correct maybe it's time to reevaluate?

Comment: sweet broken link bro. plz update documentation link

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Given your comment to the question (where you say that executing the install for a single package works as expected), I would suggest looping over your requirement file. In bash:

```
#!/bin/sh
while read p; do
  pip install $p
done < requirements.pip
```

HTH!

Comment: Right, that was way faster than trying to achieve this with pip only. Appears it did not solved my problem, in fact, pip installing from a requirement file _does_ install unlisted dependencies (which is reassuring) but it allowed me to figure out that my "1st level" dependencies list was incomplete: one of the packages i use doesn't have any listed dependencies but instead have a requirement file i used last month to set up the virtualenv. There was no way for pip to know this and I also forgot about it: my bad. My apologies but thank you for the support !

Answer (score 67):

Simply use:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

This installs all dependencies listed in requirements.txt file.

Comment: As OP clearly does know `pip install -r (...)` I don't know what this was supposed to answer...

Comment: For everyone else.

Answer (score 36):

> Any way to do this without manually re-installing the packages in a new virtualenv to get their dependencies ? This would be error-prone and I'd like to automate the process of cleaning the virtualenv from no-longer-needed old dependencies.

That's what *pip-tools* package is for (from https://github.com/jazzband/pip-tools):

### Installation

```
$ pip install --upgrade pip  # pip-tools needs pip==6.1 or higher (!)
$ pip install pip-tools
```

### Example usage for pip-compile

Suppose you have a Flask project, and want to pin it for production. Write the following line to a file:

```
# requirements.in
Flask
```

Now, run pip-compile requirements.in:

```
$ pip-compile requirements.in
#
# This file is autogenerated by pip-compile
# Make changes in requirements.in, then run this to update:
#
#    pip-compile requirements.in
#
flask==0.10.1
itsdangerous==0.24        # via flask
jinja2==2.7.3             # via flask
markupsafe==0.23          # via jinja2
werkzeug==0.10.4          # via flask
```

And it will produce your `requirements.txt`, with all the Flask dependencies (and all underlying dependencies) pinned. Put this file under version control as well and periodically re-run `pip-compile` to update the packages.

### Example usage for pip-sync

Now that you have a `requirements.txt`, you can use `pip-sync` to update your virtual env to reflect exactly what's in there. Note: this will install/upgrade/uninstall everything necessary to match the `requirements.txt` contents.

```
$ pip-sync
Uninstalling flake8-2.4.1:
  Successfully uninstalled flake8-2.4.1
Collecting click==4.1
  Downloading click-4.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (62kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 65kB 1.8MB/s
  Found existing installation: click 4.0
    Uninstalling click-4.0:
      Successfully uninstalled click-4.0
Successfully installed click-4.1
```

Answer (score 7):

Extending Piotr's answer, if you also need a way to figure what to put in `requirements.in`, you can first use [`pip-chill` to find the minimal set of required packages you have](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40074640/115246). By combining these tools, you can show the dependency reason why each package is installed. The full cycle looks like this:

1. Create virtual environment:
   `$ python3 -m venv venv`
2. Activate it:
   `$ . venv/bin/activate`
3. Install newest version of pip, pip-tools and pip-chill:
   `(venv)$ pip install --upgrade pip`
   `(venv)$ pip install pip-tools pip-chill`
4. Build your project, install more pip packages, etc, until you want to save...
5. Extract minimal set of packages (ie, top-level without dependencies):
   `(venv)$ pip-chill --no-version > requirements.in`
6. Compile list of all required packages (showing dependency reasons):
   `(venv)$ pip-compile requirements.in`
7. Make sure the current installation is synchronized with the list:
   `(venv)$ pip-sync`

Answer (score 5):

As @Ming mentioned:

```
pip install -r file.txt
```

Here's a simple line to force update all dependencies:

```
while read -r package; do pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall $package;done < pipfreeze.txt
```

or

```
pip list --outdated --format=freeze | grep -v '^\-e' | cut -d = -f 1  | xargs -n1 pip install -U
```

Answer (score 0):

The pip freeze command does not see your virtual environment.

Try to exit it and enter the command

```
C:\Users\зс\PycharmProjects\path_user\my_venv\Scripts >deactivate
```

then activate it again in the same folder:

```
C:\Users\зс\PycharmProjects\path_user\my_venv\Scripts >activate
```

then freeze the pip freeze dependencies in the root of the project > requirements.txt .