# python pycharm dependency sync

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pycharm, dependency-management

I am new to Python/PYCHARM world. I am used to MAVEN in Java world.
I am trying to setup environment for a open source Python project with PYCHARM and every time I run tests it shows one or other dependency is missing for import. So I am searching for a unified way to get all dependencies  similar to  "mvn install"  does for Pycharm IDE

Version Python 2.7.12 :: Anaconda 4.2.0 (x86_64)
Pycharm community Edition 2016.3.1 (Build on 14 Dec 2016)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For PyCharm, you can write `requirements.txt` file to list all dependencies and PyCharm will suggest you to install them whenever they are not available.

[image: pycharm suggests to install dependencies]

`requirements.txt` should be like:

[image: requirements.txt]

Generally in python, [distutils](https://docs.python.org/2/library/distutils.html) or [setuptools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools) is used to manage building resources and installing the app with his dependencies. You only need to create a `setup.py` file and use it like this:

```
python setup.py install
```

If you are looking to perform different commands than `build` and `install` you can use [pyinvoke](http://www.pyinvoke.org/):

> Invoke is a Python (2.6+ and 3.3+) task execution tool & library,
>   drawing inspiration from various sources to arrive at a powerful &
>   clean feature set.

Comment: To see how automatically generate requirements.txt file based on your *main* dependencies see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35411399/95735).