# How to get flake8 as a global package and other packages from virtual environment?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, virtualenv, python-venv

I use Visual Studio Code with flake8 linter but I don't know how to make a virtual environment with an access to globally installed package (flake8).
`virtualenv env --system-site-packages` doesn't work like I would like because when I put a command `pip freeze` it shows me all global packages.

Comment: Why not install `flake8` into the venv?

Comment: @phd because it's not a solution and I don't want it there

Comment: You're battling against your tools. Installing all necessary packages into every venv is the solution. Yes, there will be duplicates.

Comment: @phd but flake8 is necessary for me, not for people who would pull my code from github for example.

Comment: Nobody adds venvs to repositories. It's certainly one of the first thing to list in `.gitignore`. Anyway Python virtual environments are not portable.

Comment: @phd I know but what about `pip freeze > requirements.txt` ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53935334/7976758

Comment: `pip freeze | grep -v flake8 > requirements.txt`

Comment: @phd that's what I wanted to know. thanks.

Comment: That works not so good because `pip freeze` still outputs dependencies of `flake8`. Another approach we use at work: 2 parallel venvs, one "dirty" with development tools and one "clean" with only deployment dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the [`"python.linting.flake8Path"` setting](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/settings-reference#_flake8) to point to your global install of flake8.

As for keeping your dev tools separate from project's dependencies, pretty much all packaging tools for Python have a way to separate the two when listing dependencies. You can also keep a `requirements.txt` file that maintains your project's dependencies and a `dev-requirements.txt` that contains:

```
-r requirements.txt
flake8
```

and that can be what developers of your code install from.