# How to document requirements

Tags: pip

When I program, I often experiment with third party packages.
Of course, they are installed via pip.
When installed, packages install their dependencies.

At the end I want to have a clean requirements.txt which reflect what packages are really necessary for the project (pip freeze > requirements.txt).

If I manage to find a better solution to a package, I uninstall it via pip.
The problem is that when uninstalled, a package doesn't uninstall its dependencies.
If I'm not mistaken, this it doesn't. Well, and when I make **pip freeze**, I can't recognize what is going on here.

Therefore I decided to document which package installed which other packages.
When uninstalled, I uninstall them manually.

But this is really troublesome and error prone:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt

asgiref==3.2.3
Django==3.0.2
pkg-resources==0.0.0
pytz==2019.3
sqlparse==0.3.0
```

Edit requirements.txt:

```
asgiref==3.2.3 # Django dependency
Django==3.0.2 # Django
pkg-resources==0.0.0 # Default package
pytz==2019.3 # Django dependency
sqlparse==0.3.0 # Django dependency
```

When I install a new package, I make pip freeze > requirements1.txt. Then compare the files, reveal the newly installed package's dependencies, mark them, then copy-paste old comments.

Well, finally I can just make it a complete mess. I make pip freeze and understand that I just don't know which package depends on which as I just forget to make my comments or something.

Again this is my goal: when I finish my project in a year, I'd like to know exactly that:

1. Every installed package is absolutely necessary for the project to run.
2. No unnecessary packages is installed.

Could you tell me what is the best practice to do that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53935334/7976758

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems [pip-tools](https://github.com/jazzband/pip-tools) is the exact tool you need to solve the problems you encountered in your development workflow.

`pip-tools` enables you to specify your high-level dependencies (e.g. Django), while taking care automatically of your low-level dependencies (e.g. pytz). It also enables you to sync your environment to a `requirements.txt` file, regardless of the messy state you might have.

## Installing `pip-tools` in your project

To use `pip-tools`, first create a new empty Python virtual environment in your project and activate it, using the tool of your choice:

- with [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) (built-in): `python3 -m venv .venv && source .venv/bin/activate`
- with [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv): `pyenv virtualenv 3.8.1 project-env && pyenv local project-env`

Then, install `pip-tools` in the Python virtual environment of your project:

- `pip install pip-tools`

## Managing dependencies with `pip-compile` using a `requirements.in` file

`pip-tools` includes a `pip-compile` tool that takes a `requirements.in` file as input. This `requirements.in` file is similar to `requirements.txt`, but it contains only high-level dependencies. For example, if your project is using the latest version of Django, you could write something like this in `requirements.in`:

```
django>=3.0,<3.1
```

You can see that `requirements.in` does not contain the dependencies of Django, only Django itself.

Once you have set your dependencies in `requirements.in`, use `pip-compile` to "compile" your `requirements.in` into a `requirements.txt` file:

```
➜ pip-compile requirements.in
#
# This file is autogenerated by pip-compile
# To update, run:
#
#    pip-compile requirements.in
#
asgiref==3.2.3            # via django
django==3.0.2
pytz==2019.3              # via django
sqlparse==0.3.0           # via django
```

The `requirements.txt` file generated by `pip-compile` indicates the source of every indirect dependency next to the package name. For example, `pytz==2019.3` is a dependency of `django`. In addition to that, it also pins each dependency to a precise version number, to make sure that the installation of your dependencies is reproducible

## Applying dependencies from generated `requirements.txt` with `pip-sync`

Now that you have a `requirements.txt`, you can apply it on your Python virtual environment using `pip-sync`:

```
➜ pip-sync requirements.txt
Collecting asgiref==3.2.3 (from -r /var/folders/r1/n_n031s51wz2gjwy7mb9k4rh0000gn/T/tmpvhv549si (line 1))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a5/cb/5a235b605a9753ebcb2730c75e610fb51c8cab3f01230080a8229fa36adb/asgiref-3.2.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting django==3.0.2 (from -r /var/folders/r1/n_n031s51wz2gjwy7mb9k4rh0000gn/T/tmpvhv549si (line 2))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/55/d1/8ade70e65fa157e1903fe4078305ca53b6819ab212d9fbbe5755afc8ea2e/Django-3.0.2-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pytz==2019.3 (from -r /var/folders/r1/n_n031s51wz2gjwy7mb9k4rh0000gn/T/tmpvhv549si (line 3))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e7/f9/f0b53f88060247251bf481fa6ea62cd0d25bf1b11a87888e53ce5b7c8ad2/pytz-2019.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting sqlparse==0.3.0 (from -r /var/folders/r1/n_n031s51wz2gjwy7mb9k4rh0000gn/T/tmpvhv549si (line 4))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ef/53/900f7d2a54557c6a37886585a91336520e5539e3ae2423ff1102daf4f3a7/sqlparse-0.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: asgiref, pytz, sqlparse, django
Successfully installed asgiref-3.2.3 django-3.0.2 pytz-2019.3 sqlparse-0.3.0
```

`pip-sync` will make sure your virtual environment corresponds exactly to what is defined in the `requirements.txt` file by uninstalling and installing the relevant packages.

After your environment has been synced, make sure your project code works properly. If it does, commit `requirements.in` and `requirements.txt` into version control.

## Reference

For more details, you can refer to the [docs of pip-tools](https://github.com/jazzband/pip-tools), or to the article of Hynek Schlawack: [Python Application Dependency Management in 2018](https://hynek.me/articles/python-app-deps-2018/).

Answer (score 1):

Dependency management is a bit rougher in python land than others, there a tools like poetry and pipenv but for just poking a round I would try the following.

1. create a virtual environment in your project directory

   ```
   $ python3 -m venv .venv
   ```
2. Activate your virtual environment

   ```
   $ source .venv/bin/activate
   ```
3. Install whatever packages you're playing with

   ```
   $ echo "package1" >> requirements-dev.txt
   $ echo "package2" >> requirements-dev.txt
   $ pip install --upgrade -r requirements-dev.txt
   ```
4. When you think you have everything you need deactivate your virtual env, create a new one, make sure everything still works, then create your new requirements.txt

   ```
   $ deactivate
   $ rm -rf .venv
   $ python3 -m venv .venv
   $ pip install --upgrade -r requirements-dev.txt
   # test your code still works
   # create a new requirements file to be used for "prod"
   $ pip freeze > requirements.txt
   ```

I wouldn't call this best practice, but its a start and should get you by until  to decide which side you want to join when it comes to dep management tools :)