# Python pip rebuild requirements

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, build-dependencies

Using a `virtualenv` with `pip install` and `pip freeze` is quite a nice way to work. All your requirements can be handled at the shell and at a later date another developer can rebuild things

```
pip install lib1
pip freeze > requirements.txt

# Do some development

# Oh I need this as well
pip install lib2
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

```
# Another developer comes along
pip install -r requirements.txt

# They can carry on developer
```

However, if you then want to *update* your libraries thins are difficult (because you have all the dependencies in the freeze rather than just the packages you use).

Is there a way to work like this where but also update your libraries at a later date.

One approach is to use `pip-tools` and keep a requirements file (this is used internally by pipenv), but this isn't very "shelly"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53935334/7976758

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My workflow avoids `pip freeze`. It goes:

```sh
# Oh, I need lib1
echo "lib1~=1.0" >> requirements.txt
pip install -r requirements.txt

# Oh, I need lib2
echo "lib2~=3.0" >> requirements.txt
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

That way, `requirements.txt` contains only my direct dependencies, so hopefully it's much easier to maintain.

Comment: Yeah... I wonder if anyone has bundled this up into a utlit. The nice thing about freezes is people know precisely what to use, the nasty thing is that it has all these irrelevant libraries.