# Is there an alternative to pip freeze in order to keep packages up to date?

Tags: python, ipad, pip, gitpod

So I am setting up a Github repository with Gitpod through my Ipad. I learned I could use this command in order to easily load every requirement with the .gitpod.yml file.

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

My question is: inside the requirements file, the packages are listed with their current version, but I would love them all to be of the form:

```
pandas==*
```

and not:

```
pandas==1.4.1
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Found an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5900201/pip-freeze-without-dependencies-of-installed-packages

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```sh
pip freeze | sed 's|==.*|==*|g' > requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

> inside the requirements file, the packages are listed with their current version

> ...keep packages up to date?

Then put the entry as just `pandas` without any version number:

```
pandas
```

It will upgrade to the latest version whenever you do `pip install --upgrade -r requirements.txt`.

Note that you shouldn't do this in a production environment because it's possible for a future version to become incompatible with your current code or other libraries.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!.. And is there a way to create the requirements file without the version of each dependency? I am using  `pip freeze > requirements.txt` but it adds the version automatically.